# mysql query from backend python server syntax error with backticks on table name

Tags: python, mysql

Python 3.9 server with flask +
mysql 8.0.24

When I run the query as

```
sqlQuery = """INSERT INTO %s (baseball_card_id, brand, buy_date, buy_price, card_condition, card_number,
        description, first_name, last_name, profit_loss, sell_date, sell_price, year, card_image_front, card_image_back, front_public_id, back_public_id) 
        VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""" 

        bind_data = (account_number, baseball_card_id, brand, buy_date, buy_price, card_condition, card_number, description, first_name, last_name, profit_loss, sell_date, sell_price, year, image_front_url, image_back_url, front_public_id, back_public_id)

        cur.execute(sqlQuery, bind_data)
```

I get the error

> Error: '1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near ''jvtojosbauxofhevhfee' ***(this is the table name)*** (baseball_card_id, brand,
> buy_date, buy_price, card_condi' at line 1'

My experience so far tells me I just need backticks for the table name, like so:

```
sqlQuery = """INSERT INTO `%s` (baseball_card_id, brand, buy_date, buy_price, card_condition, card_number,
description, first_name, last_name, profit_loss, sell_date, sell_price, year, card_image_front, card_image_back, front_public_id, back_public_id) 
VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
```

but when I run that, it fails, and in the server log, the query shows as (note the backtick then single quote)

> INSERT INTO `'jvtojosbauxofhevhfee'` (baseball_card_id, brand,
> buy_date, buy_price, card_condition, card_number,
> description, first_name, last_name, profit_loss, sell_date, sell_price, year, card_image_front, card_image_back, front_public_id,
> back_public_id)
> VALUES('0e993307-231c-44f0-908d-b38786199851', '2222', '2021-04-28T04:00:00.000Z', '2222', '2222', '2222', '2222', '2222',
> '2222', '', '', '', '2222', '', '', '', '')

I have seen this error before and just adding the backticks to the table name in the sql query always solved it, but not this time. I even renamed the table name as all letters in case it was a syntax issue with dashes, underscores, etc.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: You only need backticks around the table name if it's the same as a reserved word.

Comment: You can't use a cursor placeholder for table and column names.

Comment: how do you pass in a variable as the table name if %s isn't an option?

Comment: Also, this works in another query I have ```cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM `%s` WHERE baseball_card_id = %s""", (acc_num, baseball_card_id))```   This is using %s on a table name to access a variable

Comment: Use ordinary string formatting. `f"""INSERT INTO {account_number} ..."""`

Comment: That other query can't be working. BTW, why is the account number a table name? In general, it's poor design to have dynamic information in table and column names, it should be in table data.

Comment: The other one does work though. I pass the account number into the query string as a variable. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Read the linked question.

Comment: Or read my comment above.

Comment: cur.execute requites two arguments: the query and the bind_data.  Maybe I have been passing them in wrong by using %s but I thought that's how the docs said to do it. I tried your way with the f"""query string {parameter}""" formatting but now it just says "Not all query parameters were used in the sql statement" which makes sense, as with this format I don't think I am using any of them.

Comment: You have to take `account_number` out of the bind_data since it's being substituted by the f-string.

Comment: All the rest of the parameters stay the same.

Comment: you mean keep the rest in the query as %s and don't change them to {baseball_card_id} (for example)?

Comment: Right. Only change the way you're substituting the table name, because that's the only problem.

Comment: that worked. Thank you for the help. It threw me off because my code editor shows %s as a literal part of the string (no color ifference) when inside f"""something""" formatting. I never would have figured that out...

Comment: In ordinary strings, `%s` is used as a format specification with the `.format()` method or `%` operator, so it's highlighted for that reason. It's kind of a coincidence that MySQL Connector uses the same syntax for its placeholders. These formatting operators aren't used in f-strings, so the IDE doesn't highlight them.

Comment: also, based on the other question reference here, sounds like I need to dive into SQL Alchemy, for anyone else who runs into the same thing I did

Comment: That might be reasonable.